# How do you write a vertex shader that does nothing?

Tags: xna, hlsl

Despite the simplicity of the problem I am facing, I cannot find an answer ANYWHERE on the internet. I have a source texture that I get from the RenderTarget I am using, which I then pass to my effect. My effect has a vertex shader and a pixel shader, but the pixel shader is the important one. I want the vertex shader to do absolutely nothing to the input vertices. The output should then get passed to my pixel shader, which will perform image processing (like blurring, etc.) on the image. The result of this will be drawn to the screen.

So basically, I just want a vertex shader that takes a texture in and passes it out completely unaltered. No 3D geometry here to speak of.

Here is the code I wrote to do this:

```
float4 VSBasic(float4 vin : POSITION) : POSITION
{
    return vin;
}
```

And here is my pixel shader, which should turn all pixels red:

```
float4 PS_GaussianBlur(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color = float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    //int kernelLength = min(31, kernelRadius * 2 + 1);
    //for (int i = 0; i < kernelLength; i++)
        //color += tex2D(colorMap, texCoord + offsets[i]) * kernel[i];

    color = float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    return color;
}
```

Note that the blurring part is commented out for testing.

So what am I doing wrong??!

P.S. The only reason I even use a vertex shader is because XNA will complain that I am using conflicting pixel/vertex shader versions unless I specify in the effect that I should compile PS_3_0 and VS_3_0 (because I need PS_3_0, I have this working in PS_2_0 without a vertex shader). So if there is a different way to specify the vertex shader version without actually implementing a vertex shader let me know.

EDIT: To clarify, my solution works great in PS_2_0, but PS_2_0 doesn't have enough constant registers in my opinion. What I want to do is extend my shader into PS_3_0 so that I can work with a lot more registers. However, when I do this, XNA complains that PS_3_0 isn't backwards compatible with lower vertex shaders, so I had to make my own vertex shader. However, I don't want this vertex shader to DO anything, since all the work is done in my pixel shader. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Does current solution works and why it doesn't suits you?

Comment: Are you sure this is C#? The code does not appear to be C#.

Comment: It's HLSL. I removed the C# tag. XNA is C#, but the question isn't really about C# at all.

Comment: @AndrewRussell, thank you. I was perplexed by all the colons :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell what you're doing wrong, because you haven't said how you're rendering. I'm going to assume you're using `SpriteBatch` and this is a coordinate system problem.

You can find the shader that `SpriteBatch` uses internally in [the XNA Stock Effects](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/stock_effects) download.

You'll note that it has a projection transform. You input coordinates to `SpriteBatch` in client space. But rendering actually takes place in raster space (a projection matrix transforms vertices into this space).

Client space goes from (0,0) in the top-left corner to (width,height) in the bottom-right corner of the viewport.

Projection space goes from (-1,-1) in the bottom-left corner, to (1,1) in the top right corner of the viewport.

Usually, for a full-screen effect, the easiest method is to simply render  to a fixed quad that covers raster space (ie: don't use `SpriteBatch`, use a vertex buffer instead). You don't need any projection matrix, and your vertex shader can be empty.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) might be useful to read if you do want to use `SpriteBatch`. Note that the code given for the vertex shader is actually wrong - it doesn't include the projection transform.

Also, I suspect it will be a problem that you're not passing `TEXCOORD0` (and maybe `COLOR0`) though your shader.

Comment: I am using SpriteBatch to draw, and I would like to keep it that way so that I can rotate and scale and tint any images I run through my shader (which is made extremely easy by sprite batch). I've tried multiplying my input vertex by the view and projection matrices in my vertex shader and it still failed, just for reference

Comment: After searching through the comments in the blog post you linked I found the answer! Thanks a lot Andrew. If you have the time, I have a quick question. I have a float[] named kernel. Why would using if(kernel[i] != 0) in a loop increase the number of registers used dramatically?

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably best to ask that in a fresh question with more detail.